# Remote system event Notification Library

Tags: java, python

Hi I am looking for some sort of library that will allow:
- multiple remote applications to register with the system on which events it is interested in
- When this event occurs, the system will sent out notification to these remote applications regarding this event
- Objects, or hash tables information should be able to be exchanged as well between the system and the remote application

The system will be implemented in either Python, or Java, and it will serve as a middleware between a database and external applications. I am not sure if such a library exists, or if it will most suited to implement this as message exchanges. I have heard of twisted, pyro, but not sure of the extent of their capabilities. I had used RPyC previously, but it don't seem to fit the picture naturally. If someone can also point out what is available on the java side as well, I would really appreciated.

Plz advise, thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a queuing system. Give JMS a try.

Comment: I think that although ActiveMq is written in Java it can be used from python.